# Assert that Ruby module extends another module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, module, mixins

I have two modules A & B, I am extending A into B in order to use the methods of A in B as class methods:

```
module A
   def foo
   end 
end 

module B
   extend A
end 

B.Foo
```

I'd like to write a test to assert that module B Extends A. Currently Ruby does not implement an extends? method but I think that would be a great idea. Is there anyway to assert that a module extends another module? I could use the responds_to? method but I'd have to loop over all of the methods in the extending module and that in my opinion is not a great design. Thanks again, peace.

Comment: I would argue that such a test is not useful. First, the fact that B extends B tells you nothing about how B behaves. Second, it would make refactorings harder because you test very specific implementation details but not the actual behavior of B. Instead I would test that B has a certain behavior.

Comment: Having good tests allows you to refactor your code with confidence. But a tests that enforces a specific implementation does quite the opposite: it prevents you from refactoring that code. Imagine that you no longer need `A` and you decide to move `foo` as a class method right into `B`. Although your code would still work perfectly fine, your test would fail. (on the other hand, if you delete `foo` from `A`, your code would probably fail, but your test would still succeed)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @spickermann's comment that it doesn't seem like a useful test, that said:

```
included_singleton_modules = B.singleton_class.included_modules #[A, Kernel]
assert(included_singleton_moduls.include? A)
```

Gives you what you want.

Comment: `B.singleton_class.include?(A)` works, too.

Answer (score 2):

```ruby
class C
  include M
end
```

essentially just "inserts" `M` into the ancestry chain as the superclass of `C`. Or, more precisely, it creates an *include class* from `M`, makes that include class the superclass  of `C` and the old superclass of `C` the superclass of the include class.

Furthermore,

```ruby
class C
  extend M
end
```

is essentially just the same as

```ruby
class << C
  include M
end
```

i.e. it inserts `M` into the the ancestry chain of the *singleton class* of `C`.

Since `C` is an instance of its singleton class and `M` is the superclass of the singleton class, `C` is an instance of `M`.

What this means is that all you need to do is

```ruby
B.is_a?(A)
#=> true
```

However, as mentioned in other answers and comments, you don't *really* care that `B` is an instance of `A`. What you *do* care about is that when you call `B.foo`, you get the behavior that you expect. So, assert *that*.